# OSRM route directions

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, osrm

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a pair of lat, lngs and I am trying to find the route between the pair of lat, lngs using OSRM. I extracted polylines from each step object using the OSRM route service output but couldn't figure out how to extract the direction for each step. How do I get the direction for each step?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-text-instructions should help. It's a nodejs application. I've wrapped it into an api; Now after fetching the directions from OSRM, I call the directions api and get the text directions.

Answer (score 0):

See the [API documentation](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.6.4/api/) for parameters to modify the response.

Passing [`steps=true`](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.6.4/api/#route-service) will return [`RouteStep`](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.6.4/api/#routestep-object) objects. A `RouteStep` contains the information you are looking for, i.e. [`StepManeuver`](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.6.4/api/#stepmaneuver-object) objects, [`Lane`](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.6.4/api/#lane-object) objects and [`Intersection`](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.6.4/api/#intersection-object) objects as well as `distance` and `duration`.